# Parse HTML with CURL in Shell Script

Tags: html, shell, curl

I'm trying to parse a specific content of a webpage in shell script.

I need to `grep` the content inside the `<div>` tag.

```
<div class="tracklistInfo">
<p class="artist">Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex</p>
<p>Where Are U Now</p>
</div>
```

If I use `grep -E -m 1 -o '<div class="tracklistInfo">'`, the resume is only `<div class="tracklistInfo">`

How can I access the Artist `(Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex)` and how the title `(Where Are U Now)`?

Answer (score 6):

Using xmllint:

```
a='<div class="tracklistInfo">
<p class="artist">Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex</p>
<p>Where Are U Now</p>
</div>'

xmllint --html --xpath 'concat(//div[@class="tracklistInfo"]/p[1]/text(), "#", //div[@class="tracklistInfo"]/p[2]/text())' <<<"$a"
```

You obtain:

```
Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex#Where Are U Now
```

That can be easily separated.

Comment: Amazing, had no idea about xmllint

Comment: It will fail on most realworld websites, anything xmllint considers as "not valid" will cause it to break.

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Use a HTML parser. For example, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for Python is easy to use and can do this very easily.

That being said, remember that `grep` works on *lines*. The pattern is matched for every *line*, not for the entire *string*.

What you can use is `-A` to also print out lines after the match:

```
grep -A2 -E -m 1 '<div class="tracklistInfo">'
```

Should output:

```
<div class="tracklistInfo">
<p class="artist">Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex</p>
<p>Where Are U Now</p>
```

You can then get the last or second-last line by piping it to `tail`:

```
$ grep -A2 -E -m 1 '<div class="tracklistInfo">' | tail -n1
<p>Where Are U Now</p>

$ grep -A2 -E -m 1 '<div class="tracklistInfo">' |  tail -n2 | head -n1
<p class="artist">Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex</p>
```

And strip the HTML with `sed`:

```
$ grep -A2 -E -m 1 '<div class="tracklistInfo">' | tail -n1
Where Are U Now

$ grep -A2 -E -m 1 '<div class="tracklistInfo">' |  tail -n2 | head -n1 | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex
```

---

---

But as said, this is fickle, likely to break, and not very pretty. Here's the same with BeautifulSoup, by the way:

```
html = '''<body>
<p>Blah text</p>
<div class="tracklistInfo">
<p class="artist">Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex</p>
<p>Where Are U Now</p>
</div>
</body>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for track in soup.find_all(class_='tracklistInfo'):
    print(track.find_all('p')[0].text)
    print(track.find_all('p')[1].text)
```

This also works with multiple rows of `tracklistInfo` − adding that to the shell command requires more work ;-)

Comment: So thank you so much.

now i became the following resume:

            Flo Rida
            Turn Around (5,4,3,2,1)

Thats Perfect, but how can i remove the space before?
And can i use utf8 because i it includes a spacial character i don't work

For example:

            Enrique Iglesias - Nicky Jam
            El Perd&#243;n

Comment: @Fabian Yes, this is why you don't use `curl`/`grep`/`sed` but a HTML parser ;-)

Comment: oh ok
then i try to use BeautifulSoup.
Thank you

Comment: hm.. i don't get it...
i installed Beautiful... with pip but in the script nothing works

Comment: "nothing works" is not something I can provide meaningful input to other than "that sucks" ;-)

Comment: OK sorry :D

from: can't read /var/mail/bs4
test.sh: 5: test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: @Fabian It looks like you're running it as a shell script and not as a Python script. Python is a competently different programming language... Use `python test.py` (or `python test.sh`)...

Answer (score 1):

```
cat - > file.html << EOF
<div class="tracklistInfo">
<p class="artist">Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex</p>
<p>Where Are U Now</p>
</div><div class="tracklistInfo">
<p class="artist">toto</p>
<p>tata</p>
</div>
EOF


cat file.html | tr -d '\n'  | sed -e "s/<\/div>/<\/div>\n/g" | sed -n 's/^.*class="artist">\([^<]*\)<\/p> *<p>\([^<]*\)<.*$/artist : \1\ntitle : \2\n/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your title starts with "*Parse HTML with CURL*", but `curl` is not a html-parser. If you want to use a command-line tool, use [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) instead.

```
xidel -s "<url>" -e '//div[@class="tracklistInfo"]/p'
Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex
Where Are U Now

xidel -s "<url>" -e '//div[@class="tracklistInfo"]/join(p," | ")'
Diplo - Justin Bieber - Skrillex | Where Are U Now
```